# Espacio utilizado por la tablas en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Con frecuencia, los programadores de grupos de trabajo pequeños, o freelance, tenemos que ir más allá del código y adentrarnos en el mundo del DBA. Una problema recurrente es averiguar el espacio ocupado en disco por cada una de las tablas de una base de datos SQL Server.

¿Qué métodos disponemos para medir el peso de una o todas las tablas de una base de datos?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio tiene un reporte que se llama Disk Usage by Table, el cual devuelve la información que estas solicitando con más detalle (número de registros, tamaño total, tamaño en datos e índices), pero si quiere saber de solo un objeto con el que estes trabajando en ese momento te recomiendo: USE database go sp_spaceused 'objeto'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existen diferentes métodos para ello.

**El primero**, más sencillo, lo tenemos en el SSMS (SQL Server Mananement Studio).
Seleccionamos la base de datos, menú contextual (botón derecho del ratón habitualmente) y veremos en el menú una opción:

**Informes --> Informes estándar --> Uso de disco por tabla**

El resultado es un informe como el de la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El segundo** es el que nos dará más juego, se trata de un script que une las tablas `sys.*` necesarias para obtener el total de espacio (datos + índices)

```
SELECT 
t.NAME AS Tabla,
s.Name AS Esquema,
p.rows AS NumeroDeFilas,
CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalEspacio_MB,
CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS EspacioUtilizado_MB, 
CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS EspacioNoUtilizado_MB
FROM
sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
GROUP BY t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY TotalEspacio_MB desc
```

La **tercera opción** que propongo es mediante dos procedimientos almacenados:

Este nos da los datos de una tabla:

```
EXEC sp_spaceused N'MiTabla';
```

Mientras que el siguiente lo hace de todas las tablas

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'EXEC sp_spaceused [?]'
```

Obteniendo algo como la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es interesante y muy util ya que nunca me puse a pensar en el espacio que ocupan los datos, un gran error de mi parte. En mi caso trabajo con PHP y tambien me gustaria saber si un script o un dato guardado en una variable ocupa espacio en la memoria ram, algo que siempre escuche pero al no saber, quizas lo que digo es erroneo. Gracias por el aporte... a mis favoritos!!

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los datos en el mismo formato que te muestran en el sistema, y no perder el espacio utilizado por los índices, se puedes utilizar el siguiente script, que aportó a la comunidad Vivek Janakiraman en las galerias del Technet de Microsoft:

```
SELECT a3.name + '.' + a2.name AS [name], 
   a1.rows AS [rows], 
   (a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved, 0)) * 8 AS [Reserved KB], 
   a1.data * 8 AS [Data KB], 
   (CASE
        WHEN(a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used, 0)) > a1.data
        THEN(a1.used + ISNULL(a4.used, 0)) - a1.data
        ELSE 0
    END) * 8 AS [Index_size KB], 
   (CASE
        WHEN(a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved, 0)) > a1.used
        THEN(a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved, 0)) - a1.used
        ELSE 0
    END) * 8 AS [unused KB], 
   CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (((a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved, 0)) * 8) - ((CASE
                                                                                 WHEN(a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved, 0)) > a1.used
                                                                                 THEN(a1.reserved + ISNULL(a4.reserved, 0)) - a1.used
                                                                                 ELSE 0
                                                                             END) * 8)) / 1024.0 / 1024.0) AS [Table_used_Space GB]
FROM
(
SELECT ps.object_id, 
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN(ps.index_id < 2)
               THEN row_count
               ELSE 0
           END) AS [rows], 
       SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) AS reserved, 
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN(ps.index_id < 2)
               THEN(ps.in_row_data_page_count + ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
               ELSE(ps.lob_used_page_count + ps.row_overflow_used_page_count)
           END) AS data, 
       SUM(ps.used_page_count) AS used
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
GROUP BY ps.object_id
) AS a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT it.parent_id, 
       SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) AS reserved, 
       SUM(ps.used_page_count) AS used
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
     INNER JOIN sys.internal_tables it ON(it.object_id = ps.object_id)
WHERE it.internal_type IN(202, 204)
GROUP BY it.parent_id
) AS a4 ON(a4.parent_id = a1.object_id)
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects a2 ON(a1.object_id = a2.object_id)
INNER JOIN sys.schemas a3 ON(a2.schema_id = a3.schema_id)
WHERE a2.type != N'S'
  AND a2.type != N'IT'

ORDER BY [Table_used_Space GB] DESC, [rows] desc ;
```

[Script To List Size Of All Tables In A SQL Server Database](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SCRIPT-TO-LIST-SIZE-OF-ALL-f097f198/view/Reviews)

[image: Detalle de la salida]